# Replace Null with Previous Known Row Value in the Same Column in Pig/Hive

Tags: hive, apache-pig

I have one data set with null values in one column:

```
price  time       id
1      12:00:00   id1
10     12:00:00   id2
NULL   12:05:00   id1
NULL   12:05:00   id2
NULL   12:10:00   id2
2      12:10:00   id1
3      12:15:00   id1
NULL   12:20:00   id1
NULL   12:25:00   id1
4      12:30:00   id1
```

I want to add value to row which are null with previous known row value for each of the id/time in Pig or Hive.

So, the output should be:

```
price  time       id
1      12:00:00   id1
10     12:00:00   id2
**1**   12:05:00   id1
**10**   12:05:00   id2
**10**   12:10:00   id2
2      12:10:00   id1
3      12:15:00   id1
**3**   12:20:00   id1
**3**   12:25:00   id1
4      12:30:00   id1
```

Many Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is what I am running in hive:

```
Select price,time, id,last_value(price,true) over (partition by id order by time) as LatestPrice from table;
```

It's working fine for some of the rows (1000s), but for a larger set (24 M rows) after completion of 100% mapper and 100% reducer the job is still running from last 1 day. Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you show some code on what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am looking something like: Select price,time, id,last_value(price) over (partition by id order by time) as LatestPrice from table;

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
 select 
    notNullTmp.price, tmp.id, tmp.time
(
    select LAG(b.time, 1) over (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.time) as prev_time, b.time as time, b.id as id
    FROM 
    (
        select price, time, id
            from table
            where price is NOT NULL
    ) a
    JOIN 
    (
        select price, time, id
            from table
            where price is NULL
    )b 
    ON (a.id = b.id)
) tmp
JOIN 
(
    select price, time, id
        from table
        where price is NOT NULL
) notNullTmp
ON (tmp.id = notNullTmp.id AND tmp.prev_time == notNullTmp.time)


UNION

select price, time, id
    from table
    where price is NOT NULL;
```

The idea is to separate null price records fron non-null price records and then, look for each null price record id in non-null price record for an entry.After picking the price for each null-price entry, we join this data with non-null price data.